# minitest: early look at failing tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, macos, minitest

When running minutest tests, is it possible to peek at the information about the errors that has happened?

For example, this test suite takes ten minutes to complete. But I would like some more info about the letter E appearing in the tests result.
I don't want to wait ten minutes.

```
*** Running FRONTEND component engine specs
Run options: --seed 29704

# Running:

......................................................................................................................................................................................E...........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's `E` for "error", so one of your tests is failing. Normally you get output that explains more. Once you identify which test is failing you can run that test in a more focused capacity, like:

```
ruby test/unit/broken_test.rb --name=test_that_is_broken
```

Where that is the path to your test script and the name of the testing method that's failing.

You may need to make your tests self-contained, able to be run this way, by using:

```
require_relative '../test_helper'
```

Or whatever the helper stub is that kicks off the testing framework. Some skeleton files contain things like `require 'test_helper'` which won't be found in your current `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: my question related to seeing the stack trace in real time, before waiting for the suite to complete